# Should the constructor args of a class also be annotated with Java Bean Validation API annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

If I have a class, whose fields are being validated using Java Bean Validation API, then should the constructor arguments also have the annotations which the fields have?

E.g.
The variable

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long")
private String name;

//Constructor
public SomeClass(@NotNull @Size(min = 5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long") String name) {
        this.name = name;
}
```

I guess the validation would take place on the field "name" after its initialisation. Do we need to check the arguments too?
Thanks...

Comment: it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on where you'll be validating this class.

If you want to validate an already created instance of this class (for example passing as a parameter in a method or `@Controller` endpoint) just use field level annotations.

If you want to validate the parameters of the constructor before the instance is being created, you need to validate constructor parameters.